# Ransack no implicit conversion of Ransack::Search into Array

Tags: sql, search, ruby-on-rails-4, ransack

I am currently implementing Ransack for searching functionality.

I have a model **Campaigns** which collaborates campaigns that the user directly created as well as others so long as the user belongs to the same vendor.

I can combine the results as such:

```
@search = current_user.campaigns + current_user.vendor.campaigns.where.not(:user_id => current_user.id)
```

Problem with this is that Ransack will not accept this combination and spits out

```
no implicit conversion of Ransack::Search into Array
```

Can someone point me in the direction on how to refactor this code?

TIA

**Adding Addition Data**

When looking at my console I can see *current_user.campaigns*:

```
Campaign Load (0.3ms)  
SELECT DISTINCT "campaigns".* FROM "campaigns" 
WHERE "campaigns"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 2]]
```

Running *current_user.vendor.campaigns* give me:

```
Campaign Load (0.4ms)  
SELECT DISTINCT "campaigns".* FROM "campaigns" 
INNER JOIN "weeks" ON "campaigns"."id" = "weeks"."campaign_id" 
INNER JOIN "products" ON "weeks"."product_id" = "products"."id" 
INNER JOIN "locations" ON "products"."location_id" = "locations"."id" 
WHERE "locations"."vendor_id" = ?  [["vendor_id", 2]]
```

I can get the first filter of current_user achieved with:

```
@search = Campaign.where("campaigns.user_id" => current_user.id).search(params[:q])
```

But I am lost of how I go about building the rest of the join tables to include both elements of data

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

```
 @search = Campaign.includes(:weeks).where('(campaigns.user_id LIKE ?) OR (weeks.vendor_id LIKE ?)', current_user.id, current_user.vendor.id).search(params[:q])
```